# Merge two list in python

Tags: python

i have a simple task but not able to figure it out.

```
a = [{'name': 'Helen', 'age': '12', 'total_money':'12000'}, {'name': 'Victor', 'age':'20', 'total_money': '32999'}]
b = [{'name': 'Helen', 'age': '12', 'total_gold':'14'}]
```

I want to mere to list above, if the value of `name` and `age`is the same then combine it together. if not the same then leave it as it is.

expected output

```
output = [{'name': 'Helen', 'age': '12', 'total_money':'12000', 'total_gold':'14'}, {'name': 'Victor', 'age':'20', 'total_money': '32999'}]
```

this is what i have tried so far (not working)

```
c = a + b
data = {}
for item in c:
    key = item["name"]+'-'+item["age"]
    if key in data:
        if data[key]["total_money"] in data[key]:
            data[key]["total_gold"] = item["total_gold"]
        else:
            data[key]["total_money"] = item["total_money"]
    else:
        data[key] = item
        data[key]["total_money"] = item['total_money'] if 'total_money' in item else 0
        data[key]["total_gold"] = item['total_gold'] if 'total_gold' in item else 0
```

i have a feeling that i am overthinking. any suggestion would be appreciate. Thank you.

Comment: Your list always contain one element?

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM no. it can be more than one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

This is a good opportunity to learn how to use `itertools.groupby()`:

```py
import itertools


def sort_help(d: dict) -> tuple:
    return d["name"], d["age"]


merged = []
for _, group in itertools.groupby(sorted(a + b, key=sort_help), key=sort_help):
    merged_dict = {}
    for d in group:
        merged_dict.update(d)
    merged.append(merged_dict)
```

Output:

```py
[{'name': 'Helen', 'age': '12', 'total_money': '12000', 'total_gold': '14'},
 {'name': 'Victor', 'age': '20', 'total_money': '32999'}]
```

### Explanation

This works by first concatenating your lists of dictionaries, and then sorting them by `name, age` tuples:

```py
In [6]: a + b
Out[6]:
[{'name': 'Helen', 'age': '12', 'total_money': '12000'},
 {'name': 'Victor', 'age': '20', 'total_money': '32999'},
 {'name': 'Helen', 'age': '12', 'total_gold': '14'}]

In [7]: both_in_order = sorted(a + b, key=sort_help)

In [8]: both_in_order
Out[8]:
[{'name': 'Helen', 'age': '12', 'total_money': '12000'},
 {'name': 'Helen', 'age': '12', 'total_gold': '14'},
 {'name': 'Victor', 'age': '20', 'total_money': '32999'}]
```

Then groupby groups the dictionaries into groups of matching `name, age` tuples:

```py
In [9]: for _, g in itertools.groupby(both_in_order, key=sort_help):
   ...:     print(list(g))
   ...:
[{'name': 'Helen', 'age': '12', 'total_money': '12000'}, {'name': 'Helen', 'age': '12', 'total_gold': '14'}]
[{'name': 'Victor', 'age': '20', 'total_money': '32999'}]
```

From there, each group's dictionaries are merged into one.

### Advantages

This method also has the benefit of being "extensible"; you could add more criteria for what dictionaries should merge by simply modifying the `sort_help` function:

```py
[{'name': 'Victor', 'age': 30, 'occupation': 'farmer', 'total_money': 1871},
 {'name': 'Helen', 'age': 30, 'occupation': 'adventurer', 'total_gold': 8026},
 {'name': 'Helen', 'age': 30, 'occupation': 'farmer', 'total_money': 7279},
 {'name': 'Victor', 'age': 20, 'occupation': 'farmer', 'total_gold': 9762},
 {'name': 'Victor', 'age': 20, 'occupation': 'farmer', 'total_money': 2853},
 {'name': 'Helen', 'age': 30, 'occupation': 'adventurer', 'total_gold': 6002},
 {'name': 'Victor', 'age': 20, 'occupation': 'farmer', 'total_gold': 582},
 {'name': 'Helen', 'age': 30, 'occupation': 'adventurer', 'total_money': 8632},
 {'name': 'Victor', 'age': 30, 'occupation': 'adventurer', 'total_gold': 6528},
 {'name': 'Helen', 'age': 30, 'occupation': 'adventurer', 'total_money': 4101}]
```

By adding "occupation" to `sort_help()`, we can very easily now group the dictionaries by all three criteria:

```py
def sort_help(d: dict) -> tuple:
    return d["name"], d["age"], d["occupation"]
```

Output:

```py
[{'name': 'Helen', 'age': 30, 'occupation': 'adventurer', 'total_money': 4101, 'total_gold': 8026},
 {'name': 'Helen', 'age': 30, 'occupation': 'farmer', 'total_money': 7279},
 {'name': 'Victor', 'age': 20, 'occupation': 'farmer', 'total_gold': 9762, 'total_money': 2853},
 {'name': 'Victor', 'age': 30, 'occupation': 'adventurer', 'total_gold': 6528},
 {'name': 'Victor', 'age': 30, 'occupation': 'farmer', 'total_money': 1871}]
```

You can also very easily come up with a custom merging function which would, for example, add `total_money` instead of overwrite.

Comment: Interesting method. thanks.

Comment: @daniel8x cheers. Note that this method is also very extensible in that you have the ability to very easily change how the dictionaries are grouped simply by changing the `sort_help` function, and no other code would need to be rewritten.

Comment: Thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you want to merge two dictionaries, which can be done like so:

```
a = {'name': 'Helen', 'age': '12', 'total_money':'12000'}
b = {'name': 'Helen', 'age': '12', 'total_gold':'14'}

z = {**a, **b}
z
```

```
{'name': 'Helen', 'age': '12', 'total_money': '12000', 'total_gold': '14'}
```

If you'd like to maintain the list structure (assuming you plan to have multiple dictionaries as elements of these lists):

```
a = [{'name': 'Helen', 'age': '12', 'total_money':'12000'}]
b = [{'name': 'Helen', 'age': '12', 'total_gold':'14'}]

z = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    z.append({**a[i], **b[i]})
```

##### EDIT:

```
z = []
for ele in a:
    for piece in b:
        if ele["name"] == piece["name"] and ele["age"] == piece["age"]:
            z.append({**ele, **piece})
        else:
            z.append(ele)
```

Comment: I think OP wants to look in list `b` and merge only on common name and age. (not the downvoter)

Comment: @not_speshal you are right. only merge on common name and age

Comment: @jros Thanks for your response. but if i change the name on b list. then your script would not work any more.

Comment: @not_speshal youre 100% right, ive added the desired method

Comment: @not_speshal was trying to use a deprecated method

Comment: @jros if i remove `z.append(piece)` then the output is missing.

Comment: FWIW, this quickly becomes impractical if the dictionary matching criteria grows to more conditions than just `name` and `age`.

Answer (score 0):

I re-wrote your function:

```
for item in c:
    key = item["name"]+'-'+item["age"]
    if key not in data:
        data[key] = item
    if "total_gold" in item:
        data[key]["total_gold"] = item["total_gold"]
    if "total_money" in item:
        data[key]["total_money"] = item["total_money"]
```

if total_gold or total_money is written twice for the same "key" is will user the last value

output: [{'name': 'Helen', 'age': '12', 'total_money': '12000', 'total_gold': '14'}, {'name': 'Victor', 'age': '20', 'total_money': '32999'}]

Comment: ha. great. thanks.

Answer (score -1):

just iterate over the dictionaries, creating a new dictionary with the values. if the value is a dup it will continue:

```
a = {'name': 'Helen', 'age': '12', 'total_money':'12000'}
b = {'name': 'Helen', 'age': '12', 'total_gold':'14'}
c={}
for k,v in a.items():
    c[k]=v
for k,v in b.items():
    c[k]=v
print(c)  
#{'name': 'Helen', 'age': '12', 'total_money': '12000', 'total_gold': '14'}
```

Comment: This could be done simply with `c = {**a, **b}`. Either way, it doesn't work for OP's use-case.